# What is the largest known piece of Etruscan literature?

Tags: reference-request, etruscan

The Etruscans had a written language, and they must have had some kind of literature.
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etruscan_civilization#Literature) gives a short mention.
What is the largest known piece of Etruscan literature?
It could be an epic poem, a play, or anything — I don't know what kinds of things they had.

There is very little extant Etruscan text.
What I am looking for does not have to be extant, but just believed to have existed.
My question can be rephrased like so:
What is the most significant item in Etruscan literature that we have indirect evidence of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess would be their religious works, particularly pertaining to divination.

In his *De Divinatione* 33.72, Cicero mentions these books:

> Quorum alia sunt posata in monumentis et disciplina, quod Etruscorum declarant, et haruspicini et fulgurales et rituales libri, vestri etiam augurales…

(Trans. mine)

> Others of these [divination methods] are cemented in records and traditions, which are made clear by the Etruscan books on entrail reading and lightning omens and rituals, and also your own books on augury…

*(Literally, "which the haruspicine and fulgural and ritual books of the Etruscans make clear".)*